# CakePHP find method HABTM, not working

Tags: php, cakephp

Just a quick question that I can't find an answer for:

Is it normal that this find method in CakePHP wouldn't work?:

```
$this->Video->Client->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Video.video_id'),
    'conditions' => array('Client.client_id' => 1)
))
```

In such database structure:
[image]

Video Model:

```
class Video extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Video';
  public $primaryKey = 'video_id';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Client' => array(
      'className' => 'Client',
      'joinTable' => 'clients_videos',
      'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'client_id',
      'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
  );
}
```

Client Model:

```
class Client extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'Client';
  public $primaryKey = 'client_id';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Video' => array(
      'className' => 'Video',
      'joinTable' => 'clients_videos',
      'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'video_id',
      'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
  );
  public $belongsTo = array(
    'User'
  );
}
```

**EDIT 1**:

Changed `client_id` and such to just `id`, like CakePHP's conventions.

Now what I get returned on `$this->Video->find('all')`:

```
    array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Video' => array(
                'id' => '5',
                'video' => '/files/cz/Chrysanthemum.jpg'
            ),
            'Client' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'id' => '5',
                    'name' => 'CZ',
                    'image' => null,
                    'vector_image' => null,
                    'slug' => 'cz',
                    'user_id' => '1'
                )
            )
        ),
   )
```

Comment: show your model Video please

Comment: No, but it's also strange that you have `client_id` as primary key and not simply `id` as requested by cake naming conventions, can you please post your Client and Video Model files?

Comment: See above for the Models

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried using 'contain' ?

Comment: Alright, I changed the ID's in the database and code and run the find method again. See my EDIT1 above. But when I try to add 'conditions' => array('Client.id' => 5) I got a MYSQL error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Client.id' in 'where clause'. When I add the Model 'Client' behind $this->Video, it works, but then I can't just receive the 'video.id' field. Cause then I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Video.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Ok, just figured out that clients_videos is unnecessary cause a video can only be attached to one client. But still I would love to have an answer to my problem for future usage :)

Comment: You have video.id here you need to fetch like this $yourarray['0']['Video']['5']

Comment: If you changed the primary key and still got error, try deleting the cache in `tmp` folder

Comment: Nope, still the same Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Video.id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Video`.`id`, `Client`.`id` FROM `video_db`.`clients` AS `Client` LEFT JOIN `video_db`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Client`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Client`.`id` = 1

Comment: Ok, Thanks Eagle, seems that did the trick. $this->Client->Video->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Client.id' => $client['Client']['id']), 'fields' => array('Video.id'))); Works now, after making the changes as Arilia told and deleting the cache in the tmp folder .